# Angular 4 call an observable after the first finish then return a value

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-router, angular-guards

I have a big problem and after hours of reading documents and solution I can't find how I will be able to solve this problem :

Basically I have in my angular guard this :

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        return this.checkLogin(route);
    }

    checkLogin(route) {
        return this.authService.login().map(response => {
            if (this.authService.isAuth) {
                return this.authService.grants().map(grants => {
                    if (grants.canRead) {
                        return true;
                    }
                })
            }
        });
    }
```

What I want to do is first to call the service authService.login, and if I'm authentified then I call the authService.grants to check if the user can read this page or not.

As simple as that but I'm not being able to get into the second call I don't know why it's returning an observable.

Comment: Btw: Whenever you have something like if (x) return true; else return false; please rewrite as simply return x;

Comment: you dont know why its returning an observable? I suppose you are the one who developed the authService API, so you should know what are the return types of the login and grants methods. Please add the methods definition...

Comment: I do, when I say I don't know why it returns an observable I'm not talking about the service but about `return this.checkLogin(route);` if I console log this if I'm auth it return an observable, and if I'm not logged in it return false @Jota.Toledo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without having the definitions of your methods, Ill assume the following:

```
interface Rights {
   canRead: boolean;
}

class AuthService { 
  grants(): Observable<Rights>{}
  login(): Observable<any>{}
}
```

The problem is, that currently the return type of your `checkLogin` method is `Observable<boolean>| Observable<Observable<boolean>>`. This is because:

- If `this.authService.isAuth` is `false`,  the **outer map** will yield a `Observable<boolean>`, as you simply return `false`.
- If `this.authService.isAuth` is `true`, the **outer map** will yield a `Obsevable<Observable<boolean>>`, as you will now return the mapped values of another async. operation.

So using that, you should refactor your guard to the following:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap'; // can be refactored to pipe + operator
import {of} from 'rxjs/observable/of';

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.checkLogin(route);
    }

    checkLogin(route): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.authService.login().mergeMap(_=> {
            if (this.authService.isAuth) {
                return this.authService.grants().map(grants => grants.canRead)
            }else{
                return of(false);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

MergeMap is basically allowing you to concatenate asynchronous operations, and of creates an observable of a sync. value.

Comment: YES sir it worked like charm exactly what I wanted. But so can you explain please why it didn't work with what I had ? it was the mergeMap the problem ? And what's the (of) exactly for ? Thanks again

Comment: Updated, checkk